# matplotlib output from remote server

Tags: python, matplotlib, keras

I am running a python script on a remote server, at the end of my script I am showing a graph using `matplotlib`.

As my server does not have any display I set `matplotlib.use('Agg')` to use the Antigrain rendering engine (as explained [here](https://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#matplotlib-in-a-web-application-server)) however, when I download the file on my local computer (windows 7) I cannot view the picture, I have a message saying *"the file appears to be damaged, corrupted, or is too large"* - my file is only a few kb.

The code below creates the picture. `H` is the output of a standard Keras feedforward neural network model. It contains data and I am sure the content is correct.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# <some code>

plt.style.use("ggplot")
plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.arange(0, 100), H.history["loss"], label="train_loss")
plt.plot(np.arange(0, 100), H.history["val_loss"], label="val_loss")
plt.plot(np.arange(0, 100), H.history["acc"], label="train_acc")
plt.plot(np.arange(0, 100), H.history["val_acc"], label="val_acc")
plt.title("Training Loss and Accuracy")
plt.xlabel("Epoch #")
plt.ylabel("Loss/Accuracy")
plt.legend()
plt.savefig(args["output"])
```

Finally, here is my code to download the file on my local computer

```
scp user@<some_ip>:~/working_dir/experiements/output_keras.png .
```

Comment: You need to do a bit of debugging yourself. Does the problem only appear with your `<some code>` or do you have the same problem when plotting a simple line plot. Reduce the code to a [mcve].